# error when transfer variable string to OLE DB Data source

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I  follow steps at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895315.aspx to implement incremental load. According to the last of the step1 , I declared a string variable in SSDT, and assign a string to it as
SqlString='select * from CustomizedFunction(Argument1,Argument2,Argument3)'
SqlString is good since I've print it out in SSMS.

However, when SqlString is accessed in a OLEDB Data Source of a Data Flow. Error occurs

Hresult:0xC0202009
ERROR at Data Flow Task-LoadData[OLEDB Source[1]]:SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEEBERROR. An OLEDB error has occured. Error Code:0x80040E0C.
An OLEDB record is available. Source:"Microsoft SQL Server Native Client11.0" HResult:0x80040E0C Description:"Command text was not set for the command object."

Comment: Based on the error message, did you set the CommandText of the Command object to your string?

Comment: @FebWind, it's better copy error messages and past them as text rather than as images. So, we won't have to use magnifying glass.

Comment: Sorry,lgor. I don't know why  the error message cannot be copied as text in SSIS. So I have to snapshot it and save as an image.

Comment: Andrew,I don't understand what you mean. How to set CommandText of the Command object? I declared a string variable which is set by a sql statement. When setting, parameter is used.

Comment: What is the error message?. Our firewall blocked your screenshot it seems.

Comment: Thanks,Sivakumar. I post error message

Answer (score 1):

SSIS OLE DB Source must have an initial column definition in order to work.  When you use 'SQL Command from Variable', you need to provide this column definition.

Let me start with a general application of the concept.  Then I will address your particular scenario.

**General Case**

In some cases, you may have a string variable that has no initial value, and at some point in the process, the value is assigned.  In this scenario, an initial value MUST be provided.  One way to do this is to use a dummy query that provides the columns and data types.

For example, set the initial value of your variable to something like:

```
SELECT CAST('' AS VARCHAR(10) AS MyColumn1, 0 AS MyInteger FROM MyTable WHERE 1= 2
```

This query will never return results, but it provides the column definition that the OLE DB Source needs.
At some point before the OLE DB Source executes, you'll need to assign the actual query to the variable.

**Specific Case**

Your case is similar, but slightly different.
In your particular case, you have this query:

```
SqlString='select * from CustomizedFunction(Argument1,Argument2,Argument3)'
```

OLE DB Source has no idea what the column definitions are with `SELECT *`.  You need to replace `SELECT *` with the actual column names and their data types.

```
SqlString='SELECT CAST(MyColumn1 AS VARCHAR(10)) AS MyColumn1, CAST(MyColumn2 AS INT) AS MyColumn2 FROM CustomizedFunction(Argument1,Argument2,Argument3)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how did you print the variable in SSMS which is declared in SSIS.

You have to declare a variable in SSIS as a string and build your SQL command using **Exression**s if the parameters for your table valued function is dynamic.

While configuring **OLEDB source** you have choose the Option "**SQL Command from Variable**" in **Data Access mode** and select the variable "SqlString".

Comment: Since the string variable, named as stringvariable, is actually binding to a SQL statment in SSIS, I want to see if any syntax error here. The SQL statement is return as a string , such as select 'select ...' AS sqlString. Then in Result set tab, mapping sqlString to stringvariable. Finally, I want use the variable stringvariable in data source. But the error shown in my post is always there.

Answer (score 0):

I am added an *updated* answer based on a recent experience with this issue.

After the steps for aliasing all the columns (giving each column a column header)
we had to go through the additional step of setting 'Validate External Metadata' to false in the advanced editor for the SSIS task. Once that was done, the error was removed for us.

I am leaving this here as additional help for future users that encounter this issue.